# When saving a Serializable object, does everything referenced need to be Serializable too?

Tags: java, serialization

This may be obvious, but I'm not quite getting my head around Serialization:

I have a single object which holds the state of my application. This object references multiple other objects.

eg

```
ApplicationState implements Serializable
    private ArrayList<SomeApplicationObjects>
    private AnApplicationObject
    private AnotherObject
```

All of these objects (someApplicationObjects, anApplicationObject, anotherObject) need to be serializable, as far as I understand.

But do objects THEY reference also need to be serializable? eg does SubObject here need to be serializable too? Does this essentially mean that every sub-object needs to be Serializable, recursively, from the ApplicationState down?

```
AnotherObject implements Serializable
    private SubObject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this essentially mean that every sub-object needs to be Serializable, recursively

Assuming sub-object is the object you are using inside the class. Yes, the Objects used inside your Searializable type also be serializable.

Where as

All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable

Comment: Is this recursive? ie ParentObject has a ChildObject which has an Array of BabyObject's, does BabyObject need to be Serializable?

Comment: @JonStory Ofcourse, it should be. If you want to their state to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as reported in the javadoc of the interface serializable:

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized. **All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.**

So if A has to be a serializable, subtypes of A (eg. B and C) have to be serializable too. So B and C should have also subtypes that are serializable, and so on..

Comment: Ah of course, I didn't make the link that each sub class should be treated as serializable in its own right, therefore requiring the recursion. Seems so obvious now you've explained it!

Answer (score 0):

As mention in java doc for serialization;

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.
>
> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored from the stream.
>
> When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not support the Serializable interface. In this case the NotSerializableException will be thrown and will identify the class of the non-serializable object.

It is mandatory that all sub-object need to be serializable.